# Toggle background color of checkbox div or label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I can get the follow code to work like I want it to with one exception.
When I select the checkbox the background color of the div changes from #fff to #ffe600 as it should. The problem I'm running into is when the form is submitted and page is refreshed the background color reverts back to #fff. I would like for the back ground color to stay #ffe600 when the page is refreshed after the form has been submitted. The checkbox remains checked after page refresh but the div background color reverts back to #fff. Does anyone know if it's possible to maintain the div background color #ffe600 when the page is refreshed. This has really gotten be stumped.

```js
function myFunction(x, _this) {
  if (_this.checked) {
    x.style.backgroundColor = '#ffe600';
  } else  {
    x.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  }
}
```

```css
#product1 {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 3px 5px 3px 7px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product1">
  <label class="chk">
    <input type="checkbox" onChange="myFunction(product1, this)" name="select_product" value="Y" />Label goes here.</label>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `localStorage` should work

Comment: Behaviors like the one you want are usually performed using cookies or a file in which you store the state of your checkbox.

Comment: Or just use .ajax to submit the form and avoid the refresh altogether.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @achref It sounds like the checkbox states are already persisting. But the background colors aren't initializing upon page load. "The checkbox remains checked after page refresh but the div background color reverts back to #fff...". No?

Comment: @showdev I don't believe so, because his div product1 is initialized with #fff (look at the css), that  is what the browser will take as color after refreshing regardless of the state of the checkbox.

Comment: call your myFunction() on page load pass the appropriate parameter, should solve it

Comment: @achref Yes, that's what I mean. The checkboxes are staying checked but there's not yet any code to set the initial background colors based on those states.

Comment: @showdev you are right.

Comment: @showdev That's correct. I just not sure how to maintain the background color state.?

Comment: @user3166459 I tried your code on chrome and the checkbox doesn't keep checked on refresh, what browser are you using?

Comment: @showdev I think the state of his checkbox is persisted due to caching of the browser, it is unsafe to rely on this, that is why I suggest using cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to check on load with jquery and then highlight the currently checked boxes.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked'))
$(this).parent().parent().css('backgroundColor','#ffe600');
  else
$(this).parent().parent().css('backgroundColor','#fff');
});
function myFunction(x, _this) {
  if (_this.checked) {
    x.style.backgroundColor = '#ffe600';
  } else  {
    x.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  }
}
```

```css
#product1 {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 3px 5px 3px 7px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
#product2 {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 3px 5px 3px 7px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product1">
  <label class="chk">
    <input type="checkbox" onChange="myFunction(product1, this)" name="select_product" value="Y" />Label goes here.</label>
</div>
<div id="product2">
<label class="chk">
<input checked type="checkbox" onChange="myFunction(product2, this)" name="select_product2" value="V" />Label goes here 2.</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a need to actually refresh the page? It looks like you're using AJAX.

Do you use a function to handle the submit of the form? Cause then you could do the following to prevent the page from reloading

```
<form onsubmit="submitFunction(event)">
      // form elements
</form>
```

And the JavaScript part like the following

```
function submitFunction(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // form data processing
}
```

The `event.preventDefault()` will keep the page from reloading which should keep the background color of your element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localstorage` or `Cookie` to store the state of checkbox and later when page loads you can get the state from them or else you can do the same check as in  `myFunction` when page loads as below :

```
window.onload = function(){
 var checkBoxEle = document.querySelector("div#product1 input[type='checkbox']");

 var productEle = document.getElementById("product1"); 
 if (checkBoxEle.checked) {
    productEle.style.backgroundColor = '#ffe600';
  } else  {
    productEle.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function using jquery that can be used for checkbox validation and formatting when the document is loaded and when the checkbox is clicked.

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var setColor = function(){
        if($("#select_product").is(":checked")) $("#product1").css("background-color", "#ffe600");
        else $("#product1").css("background-color", "#fff");
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setColor();
        $("#select_product").click(setColor);
    });
</script>
<div id="product1">
    <label class="chk">
    <input type="checkbox" id="select_product" value="Y">Label goes here.</label>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Mikołaj,  Thanks a lot for you help on this! I've tried your code and it works perfectly when clicking the div that contains the checkbox. Is there a way I can make this work when the checkbox is checked?

Comment: The function that verifies checbox selection and colors the div accordingly is called in two places: when the document is loaded and when checkbox is clicked. So it should work according to your expectations. I tested it for such behaviour in Firefox. Pls let me know how it behaves in your environment.

Comment: It's very strange. Something must be interfering with the code.? When I select the checkbox it just won't effect the background color of the div with id="product1". The bg color only changes when the label or div is selected. I've tried the code above in a jsfiddle and it works great. It just won't work on my page. I wish I could show you the page but it's on a dev server.

Comment: I just tried adding your code above to my page outside of the form tag and it works. The div changes color when I click the div or the checkbox. I'm not sure what that means though.?

Comment: So the div or label behaves the same way as the checkbox ? Maybe IDs of the elements are swapped with each other ?

Comment: If I click the div or label the div background changes color. If I click the actual checkbox the background color of the div doesn't change.

Comment: Can you paste just a fragment of your web page with form, div, checkbox and submit button ?